# Appending a 1x3 numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm reading in floats from a file, and I'm trying to make an np array of np arrays. I essentially do:

```
arr = []
for i in range:
   arr.append(np.array([float, float, float]))
return np.asarray(arr)
```

This gives me array items that are, for example, [3. 5. 2.], so their shape is (3,), but I want them to be (1, 3). How can I fix this?

Comment: This is technically doable, but highly awkward and almost certainly the wrong way to go about working with your data.

Comment: Have you tried using a `pandas.DataFrame` object?

Comment: @user2357112: It would be better to start off with a numpy array in the first place, but for some reason I am unable to append to one using np.append, so this was my shady workaround

Comment: @MylesBaker I have not, and since I don't know that library and am under a time constraint, I would prefer not to attempt doing so.

Comment: I don't see what `pandas` adds to a simple task of constructing a 2d array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reshape, to change the shape of each individual array.

```
arr = []
for i in range:
    arr.append(np.reshape(np.array([float,float,float]),(1,3)))
return np.asarray(arr)
```

Comment: I tried this initially, but that ends me up with something like [[float float float]]. Would this still work in numpy operations? I'm doing a lot of vector math, so I just want to be sure all my numbers will work out.

Comment: Not sure how you are using this, but for example if a = array(arr). then np.dot(a,np.transpose(a[0])) works perfectly.

Comment: Do you ever forget how to do something completely trivial? My brain woke up and you're completely right, I must be running on too little sleep.

Comment: ahah, no worries, happy to help!

Comment: Doesn't this answer produce a `(n, 1, 3)` array?

Answer (score 0):

```
Out[426]: array([[  1.2,  34. ,  34. ]])
In [427]: _.shape
Out[427]: (1, 3)
```

But why does the inner array need to be `(1,3)`?

```
In [428]: arr=[]
In [429]: for i in range(3):
   .....:     arr.append(np.array([1.,2.,3.]))
   .....: 
In [430]: arr
Out[430]: [array([ 1.,  2.,  3.]), array([ 1.,  2.,  3.]), array([ 1.,  2.,  3.])]
In [431]: np.array(arr)
Out[431]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.]])
In [432]: _.shape
Out[432]: (3, 3)
```

I don't even need to apply `array` in the inner loop; I can just collect a list of lists:

```
for i in range(3):
    arr.append([1.,2.,3.])
np.array(arr)
```

The inner arrays only need to be `(1,3)` if I want to join them with `np.concatenate`.

Note that the vary basic way of defining a 2d array is to give it a list of lists:

```
In [442]: np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
Out[442]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

I could just as well made that list iteratively.

---

If I make the inner array `(1,3)`, the joining them with `np.asarray` (or `np.array`) makes a `(n, 1,3)` array:

```
In [444]: for i in range(3):
    arr.append(np.reshape(np.array([1.,2,3]),(1,3)))
   .....:     
In [445]: arr
Out[445]: [array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.]]), array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.]]), array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.]])]
In [446]: np.array(arr)
Out[446]: 
array([[[ 1.,  2.,  3.]],

       [[ 1.,  2.,  3.]],

       [[ 1.,  2.,  3.]]])
In [447]: _.shape
Out[447]: (3, 1, 3)
```